# What is the right way to exit a(n) sqlite session?

Tags: sqlite

When I do a .quit or .exit, it exits correctly, only sometimes, and other times it returns an error code, that I can see from the prompt.

Comment: Well, “what error code?” What does the documentation say about such a reported “error code”?

Comment: An `echo $?` says 1.

Answer (score 1):

`.quit`, `.exit` and EOF are all right ways to exit an sqlite3 session.

If there was an error during the sqlite3 session, the return code is non-0. It's 0 when there were no errors.

This makes it practical to write shell scripts that involve sqlite3 database operations. For interactive sqlite3 sessions it's not that useful since you have likely corrected the problems interactively.

Do you have a specific problem with an error code being returned?

Comment: No, no problem as such. I was just curious as to why it was returning a non-0 value to the shell on exit. Thank you.